# Is it cheaper to buy assembled planes or build them yourself?

Tags: pocket-planes

At first I assumed building planes as cheaper as the 3 necessary parts cost less than the full cost of the plane. However I've learned that there is a "build" cost and also a cost to move planes out of your hangar into service.

Is it actually cheaper to build planes or should I buy them outright instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, building a plane from its parts (including the building cost) is always a little cheaper than buying the entire plane.  Also, the building cost seems to always be the same as the price of the other parts.

Comment: I'll just add that when you build a plane you get to choose a starting airport, it doesn't start in your hangar so there's no cost involved in moving it out. I haven't actually put any planes in my hangar so I'm not even sure if that cost exists.

Comment: @Seyren Nope, it's free to remove a plane.

Comment: @Seyren yeah it costs a few bucks to bring a hangared plane back into service, but free to remove them from service or put a newly assembled plane in the air

Comment: Yep, its; definitely slightly cheaper to buy them by parts.